# Solving for minimum $x$ given divisibility constraints

Tags: number-theory

If $x-k$ is divisible by $a$ and $x+k$ is divisible by $b$ with $a, b, k$ known, how do I solve for $x$? All numbers here are positive integers.

Answer (score 1):

You have $x-k=am, x+k=bn$ for $m,n$ positive integers.  So $x=am+k=bn-k$  You can look at the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$ and use the [Chinese remainder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem)  Once you have one solution, you have an infinite tower of them.

Comment: I had been looking here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Case_of_two_equations actually but could not understand it since I think it's all modulo 0

Comment: @user2175923: that should explain how to find one solution.  It is not modulo $0$, it is modulo $gcd(a,b)$ Once you have one solution, they recur at intervals $lcm(a,b)$

Comment: I don't understand how to actually solve for it since my x terms are partially known and unknown each

Comment: @user2175923:  If you solve it for $x$ you will find restrictions on $x$.  You can then incorporate the known terms and find restrictions on the unknown terms.

Comment: For example, given $k=3,a=6,b=8$ we have $x \equiv 3 \pmod 6$ and $x \equiv -3 \equiv 5 \pmod 8$.  There are the two congruences.  The solution is $x \equiv 21 \pmod {24}$

Comment: But 6 and 8 are not coprime right? Is there a simplification to be applied first?

Comment: @user2175923:  For solving each congruence, you don't care about $6$ and $8$ being coprime or not.  You only care when combining them into one, you need to work with the LCM, which here is not the product.

Comment: I understand that 24 = lcm(6,8) but I don't understand how you get from 3 and 5 to 21

Comment: @user2175923:  I looked for a number that satisfied both equivalences.  The first is satisfied by $3, 9, 15, 21, \ldots$  The second by $5, 13, 21, \ldots$ and $21$ is common to both.  For small numbers like this, I just look.

Comment: So you have X = 3 + 6n = 5 + 8m and so it is X modulo lcm(6,8)? Is there a more systematic way to find n and m?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8060/discussion-between-ross-millikan-and-user2175923)

Comment: @user2175923:  The [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) which depends on the [Extended Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) will get you there.  It is a standard technique.

Comment: I understand that already but those don't explain how to solve something like this. I've been working on this for way too many hours straight now and I can't find a straight answer *anywhere* on the net.