# Solving Chinese Remainder Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

If $x = am + k = bn - k$ for known $a,b,k$ and $\gcd(a,b)$, how to solve for $x$ using Chinese Remainder Theorem?

Comment: m and n are not known

Comment: Is $\rm\:gcd(a,b) = 1\,?\ \ $

Comment: Is it required? If not, I presume there is no solution? If so, how to proceed?

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of your [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/340319/23500) asked 50 minutes prior?

Comment: Not a duplicate, but related: It's a question asked to address something listed in the comments of that question. The person replying has stopped responding and the question was not answered.

Comment: As currently written, it is precisely the same question as your question asked 1 hour ago. This question will likely be closed as a duplicate. Please don't ask duplicate questions. If your first question doesn't receive an adequate answer after a few days or so, and after asking for elaboration in comments, then bump it by an edit explaining what remains unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Write $\text{g.c.d.}(a,b)=g$. And $a=ga'$, $b=gb'$. Further suppose that $ar+bs=g$, [by Bézout's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity).
Firstly, for $x$ to solvable, it needs and it suffices that $g\mid 2k$.
When $g\mid k$, just divide out and suppose that $g=1$, so that $ar+bs=1$. Then $bsk-akr$ is easily seen to be congruent to $k\pmod a$, and $\equiv -k\pmod b$. So this is one $x$.
When $g=2$, then $ar+bs=2$, so that $ark+bks=2k$, that is to say, $-ark+k=bks-k$ is one $x$.
So we have found all solutions.
If error occurs, never let it go: please tell me, thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems to introduce a whole lot of extra variables? Can you give an example instead?

Comment: It is to turn the question into solving $2k=bn-am$. And the main tool is the identity of Bézout. This is the essense of CRT, I believe.

Comment: Let's say a=8, b=24, k=128. How to find x?

Comment: Since $g.c.d.=8$ divides $k$, we first divide out to reduce the case to $a=1, b=3, k=16$. Then the problem is to find $32=3n-m$. When you find one solution, remember to multiply by $8$ to obtain a solution to the original problem.

Comment: Is there a systematic way to solve for solutions like that? By eyeballing it I can see that n=11 and m=1 would work.

Comment: I think you are trying to find [Euclidean division algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division)? If not, try it! It works very well. Now I have to depart, so later? Thanks in any case.

Comment: I can't use the Euclidean algorithm for that because 32 is not the gcd

Comment: Yeah, testing this out, this does not work

Comment: Sorry, but what I mean is that you should find $x$ and $y$ with $ax+by=\text{g.c.d.}(a,b)=g$. And then, if $g\mid k$, then the equation $ar+bs=k$ has a solution $(r,s)=\frac{k}{g}(x,y)$. In the above example, $32$ is certainly not the g.c.d., but the g.c.d. divides $32$, so you can find a solution by the algorithm indeed. Regards.

Comment: but we've already divided by the gcd of 8. This is all horribly confusing; if you would be so kind, would you be able to tell me exactly which parameters would be sent to the Euclidean algorithm and how you'd derive this from the original a=8,b=24,k=128 parameters

Comment: So what do you know about the algorithm? As far as I am concerned, it is to find the g.c.d. of two numbers. Now how can this help you with finding the solution to a linear equation? Why not tell me what you have done, so that I can help you more easily. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the initial equations, 
$$ x \equiv k \pmod a\\
x \equiv -k \pmod b$$
By the chinese remainder theorem, when (a,b)=1 
$$\mathbb{Z}_{a*b} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{a} \times \mathbb{Z}_b$$ 
The actual solution for x is of the form x+abt for some nonnegative integer t, but it's assumed that the wanted solution is when t=0.  In other words, we're looking for the solution such that $$ 0\leq x \lt ab$$  This also implies that the solution we want has $$m \lt b$$ 
Substituting x=am+k into the second congruence and solving,
$$am+k \equiv -k \pmod b\\ a^{-1}am\equiv m\equiv a^{-1}* -2k \pmod b$$
Since m < b, this gives m.
(Non-units could be a problem here if (a,b)≠1 )

---

In the above comment's case, a=8 and b=24, the Chinese remainder is not going to help since its general form is in terms of the intersection of the ideals.
$$R /(a) \cap (b) \cong R/(a) \times R/(b) $$
$$(8) \cap (24) = (24) $$
and so this could only give an answer (mod 24).  The congruency (mod 24) is part of the given and does not help.